# Couldn't call app. Bad request to "curl 'http://localhost:3564/' -s --fail 2>&1" derailed_benchmarks gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting error messages as pasted below:

```
% USE_SERVER=puma bundle exec derailed exec perf:mem_over_time
Booting: production
docking_dev already exists
Endpoint: "/"
Port: 3857
Server: "puma"
[4990] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[4990] * Version 3.7.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
[4990] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[4990] * Environment: production
[4990] * Process workers: 2
[4990] * Preloading application
[4990] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
[4990] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[4990] - Worker 0 (pid: 5013) booted, phase: 0
[4990] - Worker 1 (pid: 5014) booted, phase: 0
PID: 4990
149.67578125
Couldn't call app.
Bad request to "curl  'http://localhost:3857/' -s --fail 2>&1" 

***RESPONSE***:

""
[5014] ! Detected parent died, dying
[5013] ! Detected parent died, dying
```

I checked `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` and `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` both working as expected. What else I need to check to make it working. Is this because my `http://localhost:3000/` url has authentication enabled. I checked that I turned `force_ssl` to `false`.  I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321183/bad-request-error-using-derailed-benchmarks-gem) post, what it suggested not helping.

I also don't know why it is picking some random ports every time I run it, like in this pasted one it is `3857`. But my app runs using 3000 port locally. Is there something I need to do to so that it uses same port 3000?

P.S. Why random port I got to know from [gem code](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks/blob/1ee59f633d0cb2819674e56fdebb9bdf12f876c6/lib/derailed_benchmarks/load_tasks.rb#L96).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it. In my case, root url redirects to login page when users are not signed in. So this is causing the gem bad requests, it seems not able to handle 302 correctly at this moment. So I fixed it..

```
PATH_TO_HIT="/login"  bundle exec derailed exec perf:mem_over_time
```

Yes I also had to removed the `USE_SERVER=puma` as it was causing errors too.